Where to go for Catholic Priest who are Therapist/Psychologist?
Is there a catholic program or site for people to find therapist who are catholic priest?
I’ve heard of some Dioceses having counselors but what if someone would like to see a Priest specifically so as to get both a religious, spiritual approach and a medical scientific approach?
Thank you for your time

just curious is there a reason you want a therapist (without too much personal detail) who is also a priest, why not have 2 separate people? what country are you in?

Welcome to Christianity! Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

You could probably talk to a priest and see if that church or any nearby Catholic Churches offer such counseling by trained clergy

I believe you can look up (google) Catholic Charities Counseling, and if your local diocese has one it'll probably have at least a Catholic understanding and be local.
There is also

https://www.catholictherapists.com


Where to go for Catholic Priest who are Therapist/Psychologist?
A very simple solution is to phone or email your local chancery office of your local bishop. Such priests do exit and the local chancery office will be able to point you a someone close at hand.
